# How to convert password string to Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile in C#?

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp, private-key

My password and my username are strings and to initialize my `SftpClient` I need to convert them to `Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile`.

I have tried to cast:

```
string myPassword = "root";
(Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile)myPassword
```

It doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a nonsense.

Password and private key represent two different authentication methods. You cannot convert one to the other.

Either you authenticate with a password. Or you authenticate with a private key. The private key is typically stored in a file.

Comment: when I wrote "Password" I was not talking about a type but my password which is a string

example:

string myPassword  = "system";
var = new SftpClient sftp (serv._name, serv._port, serv._username, myPassword);

Comment: Sure I understand. My answer still stands. Private key and password are two completely different things. You cannot convert one to the other. And I'm not talking about converting C# types, I'm talking about the concepts. There's no way to covert a "password" to a "private key". It's the same non sense as if you asked how to convert a "username" to a "password".

Comment: You most probably have [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Ask for what you really want to achieve.

Comment: okay I just understand ...
I thought that was possible because, before I identified in the following way:

var = new SftpClient sftp (serv._name, serv._port, "root", "root"))

thank you